# How to call Swift initializer methods with multiple param in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initializer

I have One Initializer method in my Swift file like below:

```
public init(frame: CGRect, type: NVActivityIndicatorType? = nil, color: UIColor? = nil, padding: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.type = type ?? NVActivityIndicatorView.DEFAULT_TYPE
        self.color = color ?? NVActivityIndicatorView.DEFAULT_COLOR
        self.padding = padding ?? NVActivityIndicatorView.DEFAULT_PADDING
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isHidden = true
}
```

I want to call this method from my `Objective-C` file but it's throwing error while compiling.

**Error:**

> /Users/Desktop/old
>   data/ChatScreenViewController.m:396:92: No
>   visible @interface for 'NVActivityIndicatorView' declares the selector
>   'initWithFrame:type:color:padding:'

**Obj-C calling code:**

```
NVActivityIndicatorView *objNVActivityIndicatorView = [[NVActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) type:NVActivityIndicatorTypeLineScalePulseOut color:[UIColor blueColor] padding:10]
```

**What I tried:**

Added `@objc` in my Swift class

```
@objc public final class NVActivityIndicatorView: UIView
```

Still can't able to access the above method.

My Swift file: [NVActivityIndicatorView.swift](https://gist.github.com/dhaneshgosai/f5335f4d48c1dce1a12269e37d7ec510)

What's going wrong?

Comment: please share an  error.

Comment: added more detail please check my updated answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the cause of this issue would be using the default argument value in your init. Please remove that default values and give it a shot. It should work.

Comment: yes @iamyogish I have tried same by removing default values but still same issue no luck at all.

Comment: Check your generated header file (the name should be something like `MyApp-Swift.h`. See how (and if) the method is exposed to Objective-C in that header. This may give us some clues as to what's going on. Also, if you haven't already, make sure your Objective-C sources are including that header.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class check this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a
>   descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc.

And also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30795117/6536841).

[This apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) will also help you understand.

So the options for you is to either inherit the class of yours from some Objective C class (In this case compiler adds `@objc`) or add `@objc` yourself to your class.

You also need to add to your Objective C class-

```
#import "<#ProjectName#>-Swift.h"
```

**Real solution to this specific question**

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35185182/6536841), you will get your solution yourself. :)

That question says that `optional parameters` can't be exposed from Swift to Objective C as all parmeters become `_Nonnull`.

So I think you will need to create another initializer without optionals and default parameters.

Comment: Perfect I have created one more method without optional and its worked, Thanks a lot for your research on my issue.

Comment: Happy to help bro. Hey lets delete all the comments.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to add @objc also to the function:

   @objc public init(frame: CGRect, type: NVActivityIndicatorType? = nil, color: UIColor? = nil, padding: CGFloat? = nil) {
2. You need to create a Bridging Header. See 
   https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887

Comment: its not allowed due to this reason `Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 4 cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Comment: So try to change parameter 4 to non-optional and to remove it's default value. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add @objc to Swift class in Build Phases -> Compile Source  and call the method again. I hope this will work.

Comment: can you show the class where you are defining init method.

Comment: I have added my swift file please check it once.

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c